# Running Anaconda's pre-installed packages(ex:pandas) with Atom

Tags: python, module, anaconda, package

I am learning python and data science, and really new to all the programming stuff.
I downloaded Anaconda (which contains lots of packages pre-installed) to get me out of package-installing problem, and Atom to run code

By taking advice from many good advisers from stack overflow, I connected atom to Anaconda's python by setting path in init.coffe (i typed the following code)

```
process.env.PATH = ['C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Library\bin',process.env.PATH].join(':')
```

I installed 'scrpit' in Atom, and it seems all the python codes are running well.
However, when i try to import packages (which Anaconda has), such as panda, in atom to use, it returns such :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\programming practice final\practice\try.py", line 1, in 
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas''

How can i use packages from Anaconda with atom?

I really appreciate your help